# Netbeans Project in Difference OS

Tags: windows, macos, netbeans

I have a netbeans project created with LWUIT library on Windows and when I take it and open it on Mac OS I got an error, but when I create the project from start and take the same code and put it in the new project it works fine

Now I get back to windows and want to open the project but I have the same error, but now the project is too big and I can't copy all files every time I move the project

The Error is

C:\Users\AMIRA\Desktop\LGB\trunk\LGB_J2ME\nbproject\build-impl.xml:483: Preverification failed with error code 1.

can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Someone reported at http://forums.netbeans.org/topic27000.html that it would help to change the CLDC Version from 1.0 to 1.1. Maybe worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved when I copy the files into another new project on MAC machine, and the project builds and run, and I didn't find anyother solution than this

Answer (score 1):

I offer you using a SVN server. with this server you can manage all version of your codes and update, revert and all other management and backup commands. user SVN Server and something like Tortoise netbeans plugins.

Comment: I'm using SVN server but the problem in the properties files or Build.XML file or something like that